# How do I execute command in c#?

Tags: c#, process, command, execute, microphone

I want to execute command to call microphone config.

```
control mmsys.cpl,,1
```

I try following code but I throw Win32Exception, The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Process.Start("control mmsys.cpl,,1");
```

Comment: control mmsys.cpl,,1  what is the name of exe you wanna activate and are there any parameters?

Comment: Just run "control" and you will know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
Process.Start("control","mmsys.cpl,,1")
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx

Comment: how come ?? Can you please let us know ? How will you know the name of executable and it's parameters from the OP's question?

Comment: that is how you pass arguments to applications :)

Comment: :) , true but how you know that just by seeing string "control mmsys.cpl,,1" that , Process is Control and Arguments are mmsys.cpl,,1

Comment: because control is a very famous application that takes arguments ... e.g. `control userpasswords2` ... `control` is the application ... `userpasswords2` is the command line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

/* execute "dir"   command */
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

cmd.Close();
```

You can write your command to a bat file and execute it from the command prompt using the above method.